# Transform a file other than web config replace element

Tags: xml, xdt-transform

I have an NLog.config which I have to point to a different database for production.
Im am using [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GolanAvraham.ConfigurationTransform)
 tool to transform it.
Here's a part of my NLog.Config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
  <target name="ExceptionLog" type="Database">
    <connectionString>
       ---- Db Connection string for test-------
    </connectionString>
```

I have created the production transform however am not able to transform the file.

Here is what I have

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- For more information on using app.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

  <parameters value="Db connection for prod"
           xdt:Transform="Replace"  xdt:Locator="XPath(targets/target/connectionString)"  />
</configuration>
```

We need to change the entire element rather than attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Succeeded with adding the "nlog" xdt namespace alias:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" 
               xmlns:nlog="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd">

  <nlog:connectionString xdt:Transform="Replace"
        xdt:Locator="XPath(/nlog:nlog/nlog:targets/nlog:target/nlog:connectionString)">
    ....put-connection-string-here....
  </nlog:connectionString>

</configuration>
```

Comment: There is another target for "DebugLogs" like the exceptionlogs I have here, how do I replace the second string ??

Comment: Specify the target using attribute matching: `XPath(/nlog:nlog/nlog:targets/nlog:target[@name='ExceptionLog']/nlog:connectionString)`, add another "Replace" with `@name=DebugLogs`.